# Split a vector into a list of equal length subvectors with a given interval between the values in each subvector

Tags: r, vector

I have a large numeric vector of length 261000. I would like to split this vector into a list of 1000 subvectors each with a length of 261. There should be an interval of 261 between the values in each subvector and no repeating values between subvectors.

The vector I would like to perform the operation on is a vector of distances between flightlines and a structure. This vector is of length 261000 because it is composed of 1000 rotated flightlines for each original flightline (261 flightlines in the original dataset). In sequential order, the first 1000 values in the large 261000 long vector are all one flightline and I need to build subvectors composed of one of each rotated flightline, similar to the original flightline data. This is why I need to sample at intervals of 261 and why there can be no repeating values between the subvectors.

For example:

```
vec <- 1:261000


subvector_list[[1]] = 1, 262, 523, 784 etc.
```

I think I am part of the way there with this code:

```
subvector_list <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) vec[seq(i, length.out = 261, by = 261)])
```

which samples at intervals of 261 but with this code:

```
subvector_list[[262]] = 262, 523, 784
```

which is not the correct output as these values were sampled in the first subvector. I'm struggling to go forward from here and hope someone can help. Hopefully my request is clear enough.

Comment: It's not clear to me what is wrong with your code?

Comment: What should the first element of `subvector_list[[262]]` be?

Comment: The last element of subvector_list[[1]] is 67861 so the first element of subvector_list[[262]] should be 67862

Comment: My code does not sample across the who range of 261000 values. it currently produces subvector_list[[1]] = 1, 262, 523 but also subvector_list[[262]] = 262, 523 etc.

Comment: @Nicola 67862 is also element 261 in `subvector_list[[2]]`, i.e. `seq(2, 261000, by = 261)[261] == 67862`.

Comment: @SamR you're correct, my apologies, it should be 68122

Comment: @Nicola that also appears earlier, as I understand the question. 68122 is element 262 in `subvector_list[[1]]`, i.e. `seq(1, 261000, by = 261)[262] == 68122`. Maybe you could make a reproducible example with, say, a vector of length 50 and the entire expected output?

Comment: Hi @SamR there should not be an element 262 in subvector_list[[1]] . There should only be 261 elements. Apologies this is not clearer. There should be 261 elements in each of the subvectors. There should be 1000 subvectors in total derived from a larger original vector of 261000. There should be no repeating values between the subvectors. The code I provided to produce the subvectors_list is correct until the 262nd subvector when it starts to repeat values, i.e. the first element in subvector_list[[262]] is 262 but this is the second element in subvector_list[[1]].

Comment: @Nicola, You won't be able to meet the condition that "There should be an interval of 261 between the values in each subvector" AND "each [subvector has] a length of 261" UNLESS the length of `vec` is a multiple of `261^2`.

Comment: @jblood94 thanks for your answer. The answer you provided previously almost worked except for "subvector_list1 <- split(matrix(vec, 261), row(m) + 261*((col(m) - 1L)%/%261), 1)"
"subvector_list2 <- split(vec, sequence(rep(261, 1e3), rep(seq(1, length(vec), 261^2), each = 261, length.out = 1000)), 1)" both result in a length of 1044. Do you think this is because 261000 is not a multiple of 261^2? Thanks

Comment: @Nicola, yes, that is exactly it. If, e.g., `vec <- seq_len(4*261^2)`, both the solutions I tried would work, but `length(subvector_list)` would be `261*4`.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to meet the condition that "There should be an interval of 261 between the values in each subvector" AND "each [subvector has] a length of 261" UNLESS the length of vec is a multiple of 261^2.

If we change `vec` to be a multiple of 261^2, here are a couple ways:

```
n <- 261*4
vec <- seq_len(n*261)

m <- matrix(vec, 261)
subvector_list1 <- split(matrix(vec, 261), row(m) + 261*((col(m) - 1L)%/%261), 1)
subvector_list2 <- split(vec, sequence(rep(261, n), rep(seq(1, length(vec), 261^2), each = 261, length.out = n)), 1)
```

Check that both solutions give the same answer:

```
identical(unname(subvector_list1), unname(subvector_list2))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Check that all elements made it into the list once:

```
identical(sort(unlist(subvector_list1, 0, 0)), vec)
#> [1] TRUE
```

> I would like to split this vector into a list of [1044] subvectors each
> with a length of 261.

```
identical(lengths(unname(subvector_list1)), rep(261L, n))
#> [1] TRUE
```

> There should be an interval of 261 between the values in each
> subvector

```
all(sapply(subvector_list1, \(x) all(diff(x) == 261)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

The `sequence` solution is much faster.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  matrix = {m <- matrix(vec, 261); split(matrix(vec, 261), row(m) + 261*((col(m) - 1L)%/%261), 1)},
  sequence = split(vec, sequence(rep(261, n), rep(seq(1, length(vec), 261^2), each = 261, length.out = 1000)), 1),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    matrix 364.7354 370.9507 372.75038 372.8433 374.8698 380.1539    10
#>  sequence   7.1768   7.4626   8.55136   7.9288   9.8455  11.6255    10
```

Comment: If I run this, `head(subvector_list[[1]])` is `1 1001 2001 3001 4001 5001`, i.e. not incrementing by 261. I had two similar (now deleted) answers - I have to say I am a not clear what the desired expected output is.

Comment: I forgot to include `m <- matrix(vec, 261)`. It works correctly with that.

Answer (score 1):

you could fill a matrix with the vector and use column or row slices, like:

```
vec <- 1:261000
m <- matrix(vec, , 261, byrow = TRUE)
```

```
## > dim(m)
## [1] 1000  261
```

```
## > head(m[, 1:2])
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    2
## [2,]  262  263
## [3,]  523  524
## [4,]  784  785
## [5,] 1045 1046
## [6,] 1306 1307
```

Comment: This gives you 261 columns of length 1000 rather than 1000 columns of length 261. You could take the rows of course but then it doesn't satisfy the incrementing by 261 condition.